# Is there an easy way to remove the data-preserver-spaces span from blocks?

Tags: block-editor, formatting

I converted a page from Classic to Guttenberg and now all the blocks have this span in them:

```
<p><span data-preserver-spaces="true">...</span></p>
```

This means that all the blocks appear on a grey background, which makes it harder to edit, see links, etc.

I know how to edit the HTML and remove the `<span>` tag like so:

```
<p>...</p>
```

but over 100 blocks, that's definitely tedious. Is there a way to do that automatically? (like a "clear all formatting" like I've see in other editors?)

Here is an example of the effect I'm talking about:

[image]

Note that it also happens when text is Italic or Bold or some other such format (which I think is also annoying).

Answer (score 0):

I found a semi-solution for now.

The [EditorsKit](https://editorskit.com/) plugin adds a "Clear Formatting" option to the Gutenberg editor. It's a few clicks and it works only on a per paragraph basis, but at least I don't have to go to HTML and come back, which definitely takes longer.

As a bonus, it adds many other options such as superscript and subscript which I like to have handy.